# How to find latest record by each day - kind of like a running status by day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a ResourceStatusHist table which records the status of resources whenever they change:

```
create table ResourceStatusHist
(
    ResourceStatusHistId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ActionDateTime DateTime NOT NULL,
    ResourceId INT NOT NULL, 
    Status varchar(50)
); 
GO

INSERT INTO ResourceStatusHist 
VALUES 
    ('2020-01-24 13:00:00', 1, 'Active'),
    ('2020-01-21 09:12:00', 1, 'Offline'),
    ('2020-01-04 18:41:00', 1, 'Active')
;
```

Now I want to list the status of each resource at the end of each day over the last 5 days. It should look like this:

```
Day           ResourceId    Status
------------------------------------
2020-01-24    1             Active
2020-01-23    1             Offline
2020-01-22    1             Offline
2020-01-21    1             Offline
2020-01-20    1             Active
```

So far, I have got it to work by running separate insert statements for each day. So, for past 5 days, I have 5 insert statements. I am guessing there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Can there be multiple statuses of a single resource on a single day?

Answer (score 2):

You want a list of the days.  Then `apply` or a correlated subquery does what you want:

```
select rsh.*
from (values (convert(date, getdate())),
             (dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate()))),
             (dateadd(day, -2, convert(date, getdate()))),
             (dateadd(day, -3, convert(date, getdate()))),
             (dateadd(day, -4, convert(date, getdate())))
      ) v(dte) cross join
      resources r outer apply
      (select top (1) rsh.*
       from ResourceStatusHist rsh
       where rsh.ResourceId = r.ResourceId and
             rsh.ActionDateTime < dateadd(day, 1, v.dte)
       order by rsh.ActionDateTime desc
      ) rsh
```

Note:  This is assuming that there is a table `resources` that has the resource ids.  You can replace this with `(select distinct resourceid from ResourceStatusHist)` if such a table is not available.

Comment: @AshwinKambli If that answers your question, then please mark it as such. And as a general practice this site expects question askers to mark any answers in order to help others with similar questions find ... **answers**.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, there will be multiple records each day flipping the status field back and forth and you're trying to capture what the status was at the end of the day based on the `ActionDateTime` field.

The following will group the history by the day of `ActionDateTime` and take the top record ordered by `ActionDateTime DESC` (most recent at top) by using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION ...)`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, ActionDateTime) as 'Day', ResourceId, Status
FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONVERT(DATE, ActionDateTime) 
                                                 ORDER BY ActionDateTime DESC) as 'rn'
          FROM ResourceStatusHist ) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Here is a [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8820d/2) for a working example.

Comment: Thank you Dvo. Your solution just lists the status at the end of a day if that day had a record inserted. What I need is the status of each resource at the end of each day over the past n days, whether or not a record was inserted for that resource on that day.